# Can Polyak-Lojasiewicz (PL) condition imply local strong convexity?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

If a function $f$ satisfies the Polyak-Lojasiewicz (PL) condition, that is,
$$\Vert \nabla f \Vert^2 \ge 2\mu(f(x)-f^*),$$
is the function strongly convex in a certain neighborhood of the optimal solution $x^*$? Or equivalently, for a stationary point of $f$ (PL condition implies that all stationary points are global optimum), is there a neighborhood such that the function is strongly convex?

Answer (score 1):

Every constant function satisfies (PL).

Comment: Even for nonconstant functions, you can have a region of the domain where every element is a solution so the function is locally constant around some points there and still verifies the PL condition (e.g., absolute value of the soft thresholding function).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Indeed, it is not possible to obtain local strong convexity at each point under the given PL conditions. This question actually stems from my initial question: Why can PL conditions achieve linear convergence? For a constant function, any point is already optimal (converging in a finite number of steps), even stronger than linear convergence.

Comment: For a non-constant function, is there a stationary point $x$ such that it is strongly convex in some neighborhood? As mentioned by @Kwame Gonzales, consider, for example,
$$
f(x)= \begin{cases}x^2 & , x \ge 0; \\ 0, & x<0 .\end{cases}
$$
When $x<0$, the function is already optimal, and for $x \ge 0$, it exhibits a certain strong convexity. In this case, for the stationary point $x=0$, $f(x)$ is strongly convex in $[0,+\infty)$.

Comment: Also not: take $f(x, y) = x^2$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$. To your question though (~why can PL lead to linear convergence): with that $f$, you can check that the gradient is orthogonal to the direction along which $f$ fails to be strongly convex; so these directions have limited effect on algorithms.